# C# Fetching the HTML Code of a website does not work

Tags: c#, html, webclient

I've been trying to download the html source code of a certain website, to be more precisley from this URL:

http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=&category_730_ItemSet[]=any&category_730_TournamentTeam[]=any&category_730_Weapon[]=any&category_730_Quality[]=tag_normal&appid=730#p10_price_desc

When I put this URL into my Webbrowser (Firefox), it takes me to page 10 of the Steam-Market, because at the end of the URL, it says 'p10'. When i replace the 10 with a 12, it takes me to page 12. However, when I'm trying to download the 10th page using this code in C#,

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
string pageURL = downloadURL + getURLEnding(currentPage);

string html = webClient.DownloadString(pageURL);
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
```

it seems to ignore that bit of the url. No matter what number I replace the 10 with, I'm always getting the same result. Why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get the same result because Steam's page actually fetches results with AJAX, which means that the content you want isn't in the page you get.

Here is the URL fetched by your browser when you are on the 10th page (the result is in [JSON format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)):

```
http://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?query=&start=90&count=10&search_descriptions=0&sort_column=price&sort_dir=desc&appid=730&category_730_ItemSet%5B%5D=any&category_730_TournamentTeam%5B%5D=any&category_730_Weapon%5B%5D=any&category_730_Quality%5B%5D=tag_normal
```

Note the `start` parameter in this URL, which is calculated from the page number.

Comment: Is there any easy way to get around that? I mean like letting the page fetch the results first and then download the source ?

Comment: @DealerJoe: yes. Simply fetch the results directly from the URL quoted in my answer. But that implies parsing JSON instead of HTML.